# Why does my code using read_fwf() not work like in the book?

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I study R with R Cookbook 2nd edition. in 4.6 Reading Fixed-Width Records,
I typed code as written in book.
but my code doesn't work like book

```
Fisher    R.A.      1890 1962
Pearson   Karl      1857 1936
Cox       Gertrude  1900 1978
Yates     Frank     1902 1994
Smith     Kirstine  1878 1939
```

save this lines as "fixed-width.fwf" and "fixed-width.txt" both

and run code

```
f1 = "fixed-width.fwf"
f2 = "fixed-width.txt"

t1 <- read_fwf(f1, fwf_empty(f1, col_names = c("last", "first", "birth", "death")))

t2 <- read_fwf(f2, fwf_empty(f2, col_names = c("last", "first", "birth", "death")))
```

t1 and t2 both print this error message

```
Error: `file` must be a regular file, not a connection
```

sorry for my low level English

Comment: Did you find a solution? I receive the same error on code that once worked.

Comment: I had the same error message from reading a simple text file.
I found that using fwf_widths() to define the column names and widths resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got a file named 'fixed-width.txt' in your working directory?

Running the below code (which pretty much matches what you've provided above) creates the desired output for me:

```
library("tidyverse")

write_lines(
"Fisher    R.A.      1890 1962
Pearson   Karl      1857 1936
Cox       Gertrude  1900 1978
Yates     Frank     1902 1994
Smith     Kirstine  1878 1939",
file = "./fixed-width.txt")

In_txt_file <- "./fixed-width.txt"

In_Data <- read_fwf(In_txt_file, fwf_empty(In_txt_file, col_names = c("Last_Name", "First_Name", "Birth_Date", "Death_Date")))
```